# How to estimate maxReceivedMessageSize based on an uploaded file size

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a requirement to upload a 1.5MB file. Given that this will be serialised to base64. What is a good way to estimate the value that I need to use in WCF's maxReceivedMessageSize setting ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base64 encoding increases a byte[] value by approximately 33% - each 6 bits is mapped to one ASCII character which takes one byte, so each 3 bytes (24 bits) in the input generate 4 bytes (24 / 6) in the output). You're looking at ~2MB for the file itself. If you add any other parameters in your operation, plus the overhead of SOAP (envelope and headers), you should find a reasonable value for that setting.